# using mapData() after adding several edges by cy.add() in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js for converting a raw txt data to cytoscape.js graph.
for that, first I make the graph with :
`var cy = cytoscape({...})`
without any elements.Then after reading nodes and edges from txt file, I add them with this for nodes :

```
        cy.add({
            data: {id: keys[i]}
        }
    );
```

and this for edges:

```
        cy.add({
        data: {
            id: 'edge' + i,
            source: edges[i].source,
            target: edges[i].target,
            label: edges[i].weight
        }

    });
```

Then i want to apply `'width': 'mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 6)'`. how can I do that?
I tried these:
1) using mapData() in edge selector when making cy variable.(it doesnt works for added edges and nodes)

2) using mapData() for each edge after making each of them:
`cy.$('#edge' + i).style('width','mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 6)');`

3) using mapData() after making all nodes and edges :
`cy.elements('edge').style('line-color','mapData(weight,1,6,blue,green)');`

none of them works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    style: [
      {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'label': 'data(name)',
          'width': 'mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 6)',
          'height': 'mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 6)',
        }
      }
    ]
  });

cy.add([
  { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n0", name: "node0", weight: "x"} },
  { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n1", name: "node1", weight: "y"} },
  { group: "edges", data: { id: "e0", source: "n0", target: "n1" } }
]);

cy.ready(function ()  {            // Wait for nodes to be added
    cy.layout(                     // Call layout
        name: 'yourDecision'
    ).run();
});
```

I define the cytoscape instance on initialization and there I define the style of the nodes/edges/... .

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you post full code example please?

Comment: thank you for editing your answer. two problems:1) we need a run() after applying layout and 2) it only replace all widths and heights of nodes to 1.

Comment: it works !! i was adding weight as string!! that was the problem!

Comment: glad i could help <3

Comment: Had the same problem as OP + no whitespace is allowed in the mapData string, i.e. for my case the only solution that worked was 'mapData(weight,0, 100,1,6)'